# Can I search from text saved to postgres using Knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm saving some texts to a Postgres table and would like to query them with Knex. That's easy, but I'd like to return only certain parts containing certain keywords. So, my simple question is, is there some good way to query the database from column "text" and return only some parts or should I just query the whole transcription and do the rest afterwards?

Comment: Question asks to "return only some parts". Which parts  of text you would like to return? For example 20 chars before and after matched positions in text or what? If you are only checking if the text matches with search term `like` operator should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand. You can use `like`.

```
knex('table').where('text', 'like', `%${term}%`)
```

Outputs

```
select * from table where text like '%${term}%'
```

Or you use `regexp_matches` on column. It should work.